# Indexing already existing data

Tags: solr

I am new to Solr and trying to integrate solr 4.7 into an existing product application. I have been successful in installing & pretty much understand abt schema.xml. My question is how to index exisitng data of the product application so that I am able to search existing data.

For new data, I am creating documents and feeding it to Solr using SolrJ directly. Is this the same way to index existing data ?

I cant however directly access data from oracle as it is tightly integrated with Product and I can access only thru product Apis...so how to build the initial index for existing Data.

Please share any sample code for reference.

Comment: Using your product api, fetch existing data, and add to solr (you mentioned you already using SolrJ).

Answer (score 0):

To index existing data, you just index again using the same document id, and Solr will update existing documents. In the schema.xml you define your key using this:

```
<uniqueKey>Id</uniqueKey>
```

For initial data load you can maybe generate xml files and post them to solr using the post.jar tool to post them to solr.